# replace multiple variables in link at once

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem here which is as follows. I've got a link on my page and when you click on it, it should replace the passed variables '&awrate=all' and '&dwrate=all' both into '=high'. I tried to use the php preg_replace function and it only works when I echo one at the time like this:

```
<?php echo preg_replace(('/awrate=([^&]*)/','awrate=High', $pre) ?>
```

But not when I want them to be replaced at the same time:

```
<?php echo preg_replace(('/awrate=([^&]*)/','/dwrate=([^&]*)/'),('awrate=High','dwrate=High'), $pre) ?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how do achieve this?

Comment: you should use `/[ad]wrate=([^&]*)/` instead of `'/awrate=([^&]*)/','/dwrate=([^&]*)/'`

Comment: You could take a look at the documentation of the `preg_replace` function. It clearly states that you can use array as patterns and replacements. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php